# jQuery Rest API with optional params

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, rest, api

I'm using jQuery getJSON to retrieve posts from the WP API v2.

I have some input fields which I want to be clickable and then to append additional parameters on to the request URL.

**Example requests:**
Posts - https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?
Posts from specific category - https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=44

My question is around how I should append additional parameters on to the end of the base url "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?"

**Example scenarios:**

- User clicks on input field to get posts from category id 44 -
      "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=44"

  ### - User clicks on second input which is category 45, this is then appended to the url again as so: "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=44,45"

What I need to understand is how I can remove the "categories" parameter if none of the inputs are "checked". There could be additional parameters at this url too, so there are examples where the user could begin to append quite a long series of parameters.

If none of the inputs are selected, as it stands the code in my example JS fiddle keeps the "categories" param in the url, but if none are selected in this category, it returns a bad request url. I need some help understanding some logic to remove additional parameters if no inputs are selected.

Here is my js fiddle, i've made comments throughout to help explain what I'm trying to achieve
JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xun2bsyh/4/

Code also:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.search-filter-form .filter-categories input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
    //example request -  // https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=44
    getPosts("categories", this.id);
  });

  // categories parameter and any ID's associated to the category
  var getPosts = function(categories, ids) {

    var html = ""; 
    var postData = "https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?" + categories + "=" + ids;

    var request = $.ajax({
      url: postData
    });

    request.done(function(data) {

      // succcessfull response, loop over and render each post returned
      $.each(data, function(index, postData) {

        html += '<li>';
        html += '<article class="article-post">';
        html += '<header><h2><a href="#">' + postData.title.rendered + '</a></h2></header>';
        html += '';
        html += '<a href="' + postData.link + '" class="btn btn-primary">View Now</a>';
        html += '</article>';
        html += '</li>';

      });

        // render items
      $('.listings ul').html(html);

    });

    // handle errors
    request.fail(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  };

});

<div class="container">
  <div class="job-listing-content">

    <aside class="search-filter">
      <form class="search-filter-form" method="post">
        <div class="search-filter-content">
          <h3 class="title-filter">Search Criteria <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></h3>
          <div class="option-filters-container">
            <div class="option-filter">
              <div class="option-filter-title">
                <h4>Categories Filter</h4>
              </div>
              <ul class="filter-buttons filter-categories">
                <li data-filter="categories">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="44">
                  <label for="44>">Category Node JS</label>
                </li>
                <li data-filter="categories">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="46">
                  <label for="46>">Category Design</label>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </aside>

    <div class="listings-container">
      <div class="listing-results">
      </div>
      <div class="listings">
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center -> Ajax](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your checkboxes' `change` event listener to this:

```
var category_checkboxes = $('.search-filter-form .filter-categories input[type="checkbox"]');

category_checkboxes.change(function(e) {
    var categories = [];

    // Get checkboxes that have been checked
    category_checkboxes.each(function(index, element){
        if ( this.checked )
            categories.push( this.id );
    });

    // We have some categories selected, let's display the list
    if ( categories.length )    
        getPosts("categories", categories.join());
    else
        getPosts("", "");
});
```

... and:

```
var postData = "https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?" + categories + "=" + ids;
```

to:

```
var postData = ( categories && ids) ? "https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?" + categories + "=" + ids : "https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
```

This way, if you don't pass a taxonomy ("category") nor ids then your `getPosts()` function will return all posts.

**Demo:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  
  var category_checkboxes = $('.search-filter-form .filter-categories input[type="checkbox"]');
  
  category_checkboxes.change(function(e) {
   var categories = [];
    category_checkboxes.each(function(index, element){
     if ( this.checked )
      categories.push( this.id );
    });
    
    // We have some categories selected, let's display the list
    if ( categories.length )    
        getPosts("categories", categories.join());
    else
        getPosts("", "");
  });
 
  // categories parameter and any ID's associated to the category
  var getPosts = function(categories, ids) {

    var html = ""; 
    var postData = ( categories && ids) ? "https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?" + categories + "=" + ids : "https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";

    var request = $.ajax({
      url: postData
    });

    request.done(function(data) {

      // succcessfull response, loop over and render each post returned
      $.each(data, function(index, postData) {

        html += '<li>';
        html += '<article class="article-post">';
        html += '<header><h2><a href="#">' + postData.title.rendered + '</a></h2></header>';
        html += '';
        html += '<a href="' + postData.link + '" class="btn btn-primary">View Now</a>';
        html += '</article>';
        html += '</li>';

      });
  
     // render items
      $('.listings ul').html(html);

    });

    // handle errors
    request.fail(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="job-listing-content">

    <aside class="search-filter">
      <form class="search-filter-form" method="post">
        <div class="search-filter-content">
          <h3 class="title-filter">Search Criteria <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></h3>
          <div class="option-filters-container">
            <div class="option-filter">
              <div class="option-filter-title">
                <h4>Categories Filter</h4>
              </div>
              <ul class="filter-buttons filter-categories">
                <li data-filter="categories">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="44">
                  <label for="44>">Category Node JS</label>
                </li>
                <li data-filter="categories">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="46">
                  <label for="46>">Category Design</label>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </aside>

    <div class="listings-container">
      <div class="listing-results">
      </div>
      <div class="listings">
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help.